# How to create proportionally spaced horizontal grid lines?

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-t6fcqg?file=index.js)

It's a simple D3 chart in an Angular app.

I would like to have four horizontal grid lines across the chart and have them proportionally space so a line at 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% the height of the chart.

I'm not concerned about the scale on the y-axis I just ned them proportionally space on the height on the chart.

I sort of have it working here but using some dodge math

```
const lines = chart.append('g')
  .classed('lines-group', true);

lines.selectAll('line')
  .data([0,1.33,2,4])
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .classed('hor-line', true)
  .attr("y1", (d) => {
    return height/d
  })
  .attr("y2", (d) => {
    return height/d
  })
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("x2", width)
```

Is there a better way to do this or a proper D3 way to space the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `y` scale. If you want to keep the data as percentages, all you need is:

```
lines.selectAll('line')
    .data([25, 50, 75, 100])
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr("y1", (d) => {
        return y(y.domain()[1] * (d / 100))
    })
    .attr("y2", (d) => {
        return y(y.domain()[1] * (d / 100))
    })
    //etc...
```

As you can see we're just multiplying the maximum value in the `y` scale domain, which is `y.domain()[1]`, by any value you want (in this case the percentage, represented by `d / 100`).

Here is the forked StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-9b389s

Answer (score 0):

You can customize a [`d3.axisRight`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axisRight) to get this to work. Instead of adding the custom lines, try adding something like this after you add your `axisBottom`:

```
const maxVal = d3.max( graphData, (d) => d.value )
yAxis.call(
  d3.axisRight(y).tickSize(width).tickValues([0.25*maxVal, 0.5*maxVal, 0.75*maxVal, maxVal])
).call(
  g => g.select(".domain").remove()
).call(
  g => g.selectAll(".tick text").remove()
)
```

Note that I am passing in the *exact* tick values you want using `.tickValues`, which allows this customization. See [this post](https://observablehq.com/@d3/styled-axes) for more details on customization.